# Eclipse warning "when selecting 9 compliance make sure to have a compatible jre installed and activated..." only shows up in pre-existing projects

Tags: java, eclipse

If I create a project in Eclipse from scratch, and I assign Java-9 as JRE :
[image: project-with-java9-from-scratch]

And after that I go to project properties, I see the following message **The system libraries from the selected release 9 will be used with '--release' compiler option using current JRE 10**:
[image: properties-after-create-project-from-scratch]

If I change an existing project of Java 8 to use Java 9, as the image shows:
[image: existing-project-configuration]

And after that go to Properties - > Java Compiler, I see a different message, **When selecting 9 compliance make sure to have a compatible jre installed and activated**:
[image: warning-after-change-existing-project]

I don't understand why is there a different message in both scenarios, I believe that I'm doing the same, so I think that should I get the same message.

I want to switch the jdk of my existing project, so my question is: Is there any problem if I keep using the last project with that Warning? Or should I create a project from scratch in order to be sure that will work properly?

EDIT: List of Installed JREs:
[image: list-of-jres]

Execution environment list:
[image: execuion-environment-list]

Comment: If you click the Installed JREs link, what VMs show in that list and in the Execution Environment list?

Comment: I updated the question with than info, I have installed openjdk8 and 11

Comment: If you select JavaSE-9, which of your VMs is linked to that?

Comment: It's linked to java-11-openjdk-amd64

Comment: In general I think you are safe to proceed. The warnings are there because you selected Java 9 compliance but you don't have that exact version available. It is possible for you to refer to an API that is from Java 11, so strict compliance is not guaranteed. Not sure why there are 2 different warning messages.

Comment: I have the very same problem (switching from 15 to 8 => I use 8 now, but the warning says that jre9 is used). 
In fact it had become a problem for me since one library is not compatible with java9.
Could you find a solution for that?